# SPH-L710 (Sprint Galaxy S III) running 4.4.2 misreports xdpi and ydpi

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, samsung-mobile, galaxy, dpi

We've noticed a data anomaly recently in that a number of devices are misreporting their xdpi and ydpi via DisplayMetrics.

As a specific example, all SPH-L710 Sprint Galaxy S III devices running 4.4.2 are reporting an xdpi and ydpi of ~160. With a resolution of 1280x720, this would measure out to a ~9 inch screen size which is obviously not the case. Prior to 4.4.2, this device model was properly reporting its xdpi and ydpi: ~304 and ~306, respectively.

We're accessing this information through DisplayMetrics like so:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
xdpi = dm.xdpi;
ydpi = dm.ydpi;
```

Has anyone else noticed these metrics to be inconsistent/unreliable? Is there a more accurate way to access this information?

**Edit:** I found [**this post**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/g56jV0Hora0/-gaFVmPzxigJ) regarding xdpi/ydpi inaccuracies. Both Romain and Dianne seem to acknowledge the issue - so the fact that the DisplayMetrics docs don't make note of these unreliable properties seems quite irresponsible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API 17 you can call `getRealMetrics` to get more accurate results.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(dm);

xdpi = dm.xdpi;
ydpi = dm.ydpi;
```

[From Display documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html)

> public void getRealMetrics (DisplayMetrics outMetrics)
>
> Added in API level 17 Gets display metrics based on the real size of
>   this display.
>
> The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display.
>
> The real size may be smaller than the physical size of the screen when
>   the window manager is emulating a smaller display (using adb shell am
>   display-size).
>
> Parameters outMetrics A DisplayMetrics object to receive the metrics.

Comment: Thanks Dalija, however I work on a third-party library and as such can't consistently rely on methods added this recently.

I'll keep this in mind for any application projects that I work on in the future :)